# How to obtain the language of the string returned by i18next.t?

Tags: javascript, i18next

Let's say I have two translation resources (i.e. languages). One resource contains values for all the keys used in the software. This resource (here referred to as "en") is configured as fallback. The other resource (here referred to as "cn") does not have values for all keys. Let's assume the default language is "cn".

Now we can look up a key using `const translation = t("some_key")`. **Edit**: Thus, it could be that `translation` is now taken from "cn" or "en", depending on whether it is defined in "cn".

How to determine the language of `translation`; or more generally, how to have i18next look up some key and also return information about the used resource?

I'm not interested in approaches scanning all the resources for `translation`, nor in heuristic approaches based on the contents of `translation`.

Reason for the question: I want to apply the correct [`lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) attribute in the browser on a certain DOM element. The localization is run on the server-side and transmitted via JSON – so this is not about `i18next-react`.

Comment: I guess it'll come down to scanning via [`exists("some_key", {lng: "cn"})`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#exists) - at least if you want to use only the public API methods

Comment: Thank you! `i18n.languages.find((language) => i18n.exists("some_key", {lng: language}))` seems to work! Unfortunately, it reimplements something which already happens inside the `t` function.

Comment: Yes, it's a shame. I'd recommend to issue a feature request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

internally i18next has a resolve function that returns the used language…

You may try to access i18next.translator.resolve(key, options)
but like said this is undocumented and not an official public interface.

**Edit: Since v21.7.0 there is a new option `returnDetails` that can be set to true to get all relevant information.**

```
  const resolved = t('key', { returnDetails: true });
  resolved.res;
  resolved.usedKey;
  resolved.exactUsedKey;
  resolved.usedNS;
  resolved.usedLng;
```

Comment: No,  `resolvedLanguage` is not what the OP is looking for. The second part of your answer is

Comment: Thank you. Yep, that internal method (currently) provides a an object like `{ res: 'the treanslation', usedKey: 'some.key', exactUsedKey: 'some.key', usedLng: 'en', usedNS: 'some_ns' }`.

Comment: Please (re)move the `resolvedLanguage` part (down). Then I'll accept your answerr.

Comment: removed the resolvedLanguge part

Answer (score 0):

If is version 0.70 Change returnDetails from `true` to `false`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to get the locale for i18n. For example, in Vue 2, you can get it with:

```
let lang = this.$i18n.locale //return lang set ('es', 'en', 'cn', 'fr', etc)
```

Comment: Thank you; but this does not answer my question. Yes, it is possible to find out the current default locale, but when the key is not defined in the current default locale, i18next will use the fallback locale. I'm interested in whether i18next uses the default or the fallback locale for some key.

Comment: I see. Maybe you need to disable the fallback. I understand that fallback is the default lang, so if some key does not exists in locale file then i18n will use the fallback that you set. I am not sure that default lang and fallback lang are differents.

Comment: Maybe I should have written "detected locale of the user" instead of "default locale". I meant the former.